# Be it............. or grammar

Tags: subjunctive-mood, syntactic-analysis

Can anyone please describe the use of "be it   or " grammar, I have checked internet but couldn't find anything that me help.

with regards

Comment: Yusuf, we need more information about this. Can you give us a sentence with "be it or" in?

Comment: << Fee-fi-fo-fum,/
I smell the blood of an Englishman;/
**Be he** alive, **or** be he dead/
I'll grind his bones to make my bread. >> It's archaic, a subjunctive usage; nowadays we'd say 'Whether he's dead or alive, ...'.

Comment: You need to give some examples or references.

Answer (score 13):

It's an archaic construction, inverting the verb and the subject, and using the (nearly obsolete) subjunctive form of the verb, to convey a conditional.

It survives much more in the past (where, apart from *were*, the subjunctive is the same as the ordinary past). So:

> *Had I known ...* = *If I had known ...*
>
> *Had he seen it, ...* = *If he had seen it, ...*
>
> *Should you want me, ...* = *If you should want me, ...* = *If you wanted me, ...*
>
> *Were I to say that, ...* = *If I were to say that, ...* = *If I said that, ...*

These past forms are all somewhat literary, but occasionally used even in speech.

The following present forms are even more literary, and rarely used except to be deliberately old-fashioned:

> *Be he good or evil, ...* = *Whether he is good or evil, ...*
>
> *Be it so or not, ...* = *Whether it is so or not, ...*

Comment: I don't understand the role of "should" in "if you should want me". Since "should" is somewhat commanding, why does it go with "if"?

Comment: @Ooker: this is another old-fashioned use. After _if_, _should_ does not have any sense of obligation, just of possibility. _If you should want me_ is a little more uncertain or tentative than _if you wanted me_.